# CQRS - Generate multiple commands from one form

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs

I'm stuck with one problem and I don't know what should I do.

My domain:
I've a **Booking** entity, root of the *booking business context*.
Inside the **Booking** exist the collection of **Event(s)**, that is the list of real events created by the user. **Booking** looks a bit useless, but the whole system links the **Booking** to other entities, so it's really the root of the business.
An **Event** could have text notes, hence I've created a **Notes** entity. I use an entity because the notes could change in the time, they're linked to an **Event** and cannot be shared. **Notes** actually are bound inside the *booking business context* and aggregated to the **Booking** root entity.

Form (create event):
I've a form used to submit "Events". Actually, the data of the form generates a command with all the information that's needed to create a new **Event** and, if the user wants, its **Notes**.

Command (create event):
From the form a command is created and sent to the server. The command has the data of the event.
The handler, on the server, operates on the main entity, **Booking**, creating a new **Event**. The **Event** could have or not **Notes**, according to what the user has put in the form.

Other commands that the *booking business context* handles are:

- delete an event
- cancel an event (creates a special event for events that cannot take place), in future it could be used also to add a note (why the event was cancelled)
- create a backup event for events cancelled

Another command, that's actually inside this context, is

- update notes for an event

**Here comes my question:**
being able to be changed without having to deal with **Event**, could **Notes** be promoted as root entities and have they're business context? So, I'll end up with one context for *Bookings* and one for *Notes*.
Actually, to change the **Notes** and stay in the DDD context, hence don't expose too much, I've to make some "jumps" to execute the changes. It works, yes, but it's ugly. Maybe it's much more elegant, and bounded to the right contexts, if I split the things.

On the other side, if the answer is **yes**, how could I handle the first command, that generates the **Event** with the **Notes**? The same question would apply for the cancel.
I cannot fire two commands from the form, one depends from the other so the sequence is important.
It's also hard to create an handler (a event listener, at the end) that, after the create/cancel are successfully completed, it fires a second command to change the **Notes**. How can I identify the right **Event**? The listener must be created with the data sent by the form, to match the event to handle.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "context", is it "bounded context" from DDD?

Comment: Yes, I've just used the wrong name. Bounded context, instead of business context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Inside the Booking exist the collection of Event(s), that is the list
>   of real events created by the user. Booking looks a bit useless, but
>   the whole system links the Booking to other entities, so it's really
>   the root of the business.

From what I understand, there are no invariants that `Booking aggregate root` must protect. Even if an `Event` belong to a `Booking` if there are no rules that state that some combination of events should not exist then `Event` should be also an `Aggregate root`.

So, the `CreateEventCommand` should contain the `BookingId`, `EventId` and an optional `notes`.

> Notes actually are bound inside the booking business context and
>   aggregated to the Booking root entity

I don't quite agree with this. Notes belong to an `Event` and an `Event` belongs to an `Booking` so it is normal that a `Note` is linked to a `Booking` but there are no invariants that link a `Note` to a `Booking`, only the association by `ID` which is permitted by the `DDD` in any case.

> could Notes be promoted as root entities and have they're business context?

Yes, if there are no invariants that must be protected by the `Event AR`. Then, the `CreateNewNoteCommand` should contain the `BookingId` and the `EventId`.

> It's also hard to create an handler (a event listener, at the end)
>   that, after the create/cancel are successfully completed, it fires a
>   second command to change the Notes. How can I identify the right
>   Event? The listener must be created with the data sent by the form, to
>   match the event to handle.

Indeed, the design gave you a feedback that you did it wrong. If you design your `Aggregates` right then this situation should not occur. If things seem to become very complicated then go back and rethink your design. DDD is much about refactoring.

Comment: Mhh... Indeed, I was thinking if <code>Event</code> must be also an <code>Aggregate root</code>. Up to now, the reason that I've not done it is that <code>Booking</code> is created for a limited range of time (a Semester). An <code>Event</code> cannot be created outside the boundaries of the semester. That control should and could be done only inside a <code>Booking</code>.

Comment: @user3604315 It does not matter. If a `Booking` can not be created then you don't have an `ID` for it and then you can't create the `CreateEventCommand` . This is not a real `Aggregate` invariant.

Comment: About the `Notes`, they're effectively bound to `Event`, I've written it wrong. And, indeed, the `Event` has no invariants to protect. So, they could be promoted as `Aggregate root`.

But, now they're entities because the db needs an id (yes, it's a sequence and I've no control - little control - on it). I'm thinking if they could be treated as a special case of mutable value objects. Indeed they exists only together with an `Event`. This would simplify everything, I think.

Comment: Finally, if I promote `Event` as `Aggregate root`, where can I control that the dates are inside the semester? Inside the command handler, should I load the `Booking` and check if the dates are "compatible"?

Comment: I don't see the problem. An `aggregate root` can have `sub-entities`, you don't need `mutable VO`. Please note that in DDD the `aggregate root` creates all nested entities.

Comment: Wait, so `Booking` has invariants to protect!

Comment: Yes, it's in the first (ugly) comment. No `Event` could be created if outside the boundaries of the semester. But, on the other side, it's true that I never create a `Booking`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141624/discussion-between-user3604315-and-constantin-galbenu).

Comment: So, the `CreateEventCommand` goes to the `Booking` aggregate (which must at least exist, probably other constraints)? But then the events produced as the result only pertain to the newborn `Event` aggregate?

Comment: @MihailMalostanidis The aggregate commands are executed (directly or indirectly) by the owning Aggregate; then the domain events that are generated by this command execution are also owned by the same Aggregate. So, what you are saying/asking is not quite correct. For example, if some domain events are emitted by the Booking then they are owned only by the `Booking, not the `Event`. The `Event` could execute only commands it owns. If one event must reach another Aggregate then you need a Saga/Process manager that converts events to commands that are then executed by this Aggregate.